# Using UISlider for updating Strings in a Label rather than a Int/Double etc

Tags: swift, swift3, uislider

Im trying to get a UISlider to give me String values based on its position within the, "slide bar" shall we say.

What I am looking for is if the Int value of the Slider is 1 then the textLabel will be "Daily" as per below:

```
1 = "Daily"
2 = "Weekly"
3 = "Monthly"
4 = "Quarterly"
5 = "Annually"
```

I know it would be easier to use the UIPicker but in all honesty it will ruin the design of the app :(

here is my code so far... Note* I have put both the Outlet & Action.

```
@IBAction func durationAction(_ sender: UISlider) {

    durationLabel.text = "\(Int(durationSlider.value))"

if durationSlider.value == 1
{
    self.durationLabel.text = "Daily"
}
if durationSlider.value == 2
{
    self.durationLabel.text = "Weekly"
}
if durationSlider.value == 3
{
    self.durationLabel.text = "Monthly"
}
if durationSlider.value == 4
{
    self.durationLabel.text = "Quarterly"
}
if durationSlider.value == 5
{
    self.durationLabel.text = "Annually"
}
```

The above code only gives me the first and last positions.  Which clearly means im doing something wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. - Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the slider are `Float`s.  You should round them to the nearest `Int` before checking.  If you put your `String`s into an array, you could select them directly.

```
@IBAction func durationAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let intervals = ["Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Annually"]
    self.durationLabel.text = intervals[Int(sender.value.rounded()) - 1]
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and shortens the code a lot thanks @vacawama

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
@IBAction func durationAction(_ sender: UISlider)
{
    let integerValue = Int(sender.value)

    self.durationLabel.text = "\(integerValue)"

    switch integerValue {
    case 1 : print("Daily")
    case 2 : print("Weekly")
    case 3 : print("Monthly")
    case 4 : print("Quarterly")
    case 5 : print("Annually")
    default : ()
    }
}
```